Streamplot in Julia with vectors
In mathematica there is function called ListStreamPlot. One of its functionality is generating a streamplot from vectors.
ListStreamPlot[{{{x,y},{vx,vy}},...}] where (x,y) are coordinates of (vx,vy) vector. I want to create similar plot in Julia.
I tried interpolation but my data is not evenly spaced and I had also problem with this. Maybe there is better way to do this? Or maybe there is a similar function in julia already?
